# Fabric js overlay text in custom controls

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I implemented an application based on Fabric js, and I changed default controls (normal squares) with custom images and functions (as remove object, etc.), modifying fabric code.

It works fine, but I want to add an overlay message explaining what does each control when you stay over the control 1 or 2 seconds.

It´s possible? If the answer is yes, How could implement this feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please provide some fiddle or snaps what exactly you want?

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mashabak/rba1yqdy/7/ I want to show a message when you put mouse over every control to tell user what does this control (rotate, resize, delete, etc). The effect I want is equal that when you put mouse over an html image that have "title" parameter (this parameter shows text in title over the image).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle. i have added "Fabric js Custom Controls" to one label and i have done code in JavaScript at the end on mouse over and i have set timeout for 500 milliseconds so user will get alert on mouse over of that label, same thing you can do in fabric js custom images. I have done code as follow:

```
$('#demo').on('mouseover',function(){
setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")}, 500);
});
```

Comment: It´s a good idea, but How can I add an event handler to particular control in fabric?

Comment: you can not add eventhandler to fabric controls, you can look at [this](http://fabricjs.com/hovering/) link, and you have to make your own code to get hover on controls.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will try to do the job using event "mouse:move", although it isn´t the method that I would have liked more, because it is an event that is firing all time. When I have something implemented I will put it here. Thanks again.